# Just installed 14.04 in place of XP, no Wireless connections showing in Network manager

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, broadcom

I just upgraded my Samsung NC10 netbook with Broadcom BCM 3411 WLAN to 14.04.

I'm not seeing any wireless connection choice under Network Manager, but it connects just fine on ethernet.

Ubuntu newbie, so may be missing something obvious.

Ran `rfkill list all`:

```
sudo rfkill list all 
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: samsung-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Also ran `lshw -class network`:

```
sudo lshw -class network
  *-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4311 802.11a/b/g
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=wl latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:f0100000-f0103fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 88E8040 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Marvell Technology Group Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 13
       serial: 00:13:77:d1:ff:97
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=sky2 driverversion=1.30 duplex=full ip=10.0.0.47 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:42 memory:f0200000-f0203fff ioport:2000(size=256)
```

All assistance much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if this will work with 14.04, but you may want to check out Samsung tools, as referred to here... it's possible that your device doesn't actually have WiFi toggled on... http://linuxg.net/how-to-fix-the-backlight-bluetooth-wireless-problems-and-enable-the-fn-keys-on-samsung-laptops-running-ubuntu/

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: Thanks @kendor, tried to install Samsung Tools, but got an error, "unable to locate package samsung-tools"

Comment: Thanks @wildman, results of script run at http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7395995/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do with an iternet connection:

```
sudo apt-get purge --remove bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe b43
```

wireless should now be working.

Comment: that did the trick - thanks you so much, I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try running Additional Drivers and see if an option comes up for your Broadcom wireless driver. Failing that try holding Fn and tapping F9 as this should toggle the wireless on and off (watch for an LED status change) See page 87 of the [manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTPCr.jpg) you'll note that the wifi is an option that may or may not be installed. If not you may need to acquire a USB wifi adaptor

Comment: ...and how do you do it in 14.04?

Comment: @mikewhatever  same way

Comment: Thanks, I did try that, but no available drivers came up.
However I did find this post, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#A12.04_.28Precise_Pangolin.29_-_12.10_.28Quantal_Quetzal.29-1, and updated B43 drivers as suggested, but still seeing no difference. I still think there may be something simpla that I am missing here...

Comment: @user277954 as Kendor said "it's possible that your device doesn't actually have WiFi toggled on.." Lasptops often have a swirch or Fn key to toggle the state of wifi and a led to indicate status. researching your model

Comment: Your Bluetooth is Broadcom, Your wireless is Atheros provided your true model number is NP-NC10

Comment: @user277954 Edited answer. I hope this works for you!

Comment: @ElderGeek, Yes, it is NP-NC10. Thanks for checking! However, when I run lshw -c network, it shows the Broadcom as "description: Network Controller, product: BCM4311 802.11a/b/g, Vendor: Broadcom Corporation". That sounds like a wireless card to me??

Comment: @user277954 Bluetooth is also a wireless network, but it's not wifi

Comment: @eldergeek Thanks! Shouldn't the Atheros card show up too when I run lshw -c network?

Comment: If installed, yes. Perhaps the specs in the manual are wrong? if so this may be a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcm43xx

Comment: @ElderGeek - That thread looks like the same issue, thanks, will check it out. I did just run lspci -vnn | grep Network
[sudo] password for richard: 
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11a/b/g [14e4:4312] (rev 01)
richard@richard-NC10:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions. - pretty much identical to that thread!